# return a boolean from PHP prepared statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

This is a really simple query to check if a truck is available(theoretically).
I am not very good with PHP, but trying to learn prepared statements all the same.

```
function truck_available($plate) {
$query = "(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `trucks` WHERE `plate` = '$plate')";

$result = $db->query($query);
$result = $result->fetch();

echo $result[0];
}
```

The aim here is to return a boolean in the simplest newbie friendly fashion.
I came across this '? true : false' which i really like the look off. But although i implemented it, it felt like there could be a more efficient way.

Like so..

```
$result = ($result[0] > 0)? true : false;
```

Is there a way that I can return a boolean value straight from the query?

I tried this.. (But my knowledge prevented me from understand how to implement it, or why it wouldn't work.)

```
$query = "((SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `trucks` WHERE `plate` = '$plate') > 1)? true : false";
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: SQL and PHP are different. You cannot use PHP inside SQL.

Comment: Please make a point to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Things like `$plate` should not be directly in your query.

Comment: @user2989408 That was a bad title, I mean inside of PHP.  

Tadman, thanks.. I'm aware of binding, which i will approach after this.

Comment: you could use a mysql IF() function

Comment: "Is there a way that I can return a boolean value straight from the query?" Is there a good reason why you want to do this, or is it just your lack of php experience that makes you want to avoid the php coding part of it?  I feel like you're going to get convoluted sql answers when what you really need is a straightforward way to display the result.

Comment: Dagon, intrigued! Certainly checking this out.. Looks like Ravinder also recommends this.

Comment: I don't see any prepared statement here.

Comment: I still don't get why this is necessary.  PHP can literally do "some_number > 0 ? true : false" a million times per second.  There's no optimization to be found here.

Comment: @DigitalChris I am trying to replicate this piece of code.
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `trucks` WHERE `plate` = '$plate' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;

Comment: @Dave I think it can probably do more than a million per second =) My crappy laptop does 1 million in 0.17 sec. Anyway.

Comment: I see you've accepted an answer, but in your comment to me there is an important detail missing: you want to match on the plate `AND active = 1` which you neglected to include in your question. If that's important to the result, make sure to include that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess again bad word. Not entirely sure what it constitues.. but making a push in that direction. I assume binding values makes the difference?

Comment: @user2950370: Pretty much (so, per Ant's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your SQL statement a little bit and capture either `true` or `false` in return as query result.

```
$query = "SELECT if( COUNT(`id`) > 0, true, false ) "
         . " FROM `trucks` WHERE `plate` = '$plate'";
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) > 0 "  // you can also avoid using if
         . " FROM `trucks` WHERE `plate` = '$plate'";
```

However you need to loop through the query result to find if it is `true` or `false`.

Comment: This works, but doing type casting in your query is pretty ugly business and better done in the application code.

Comment: @tadman: Though I agree in general, this is not so much type casting as the semantic transformation of data. In this instance I think it makes perfect sense: he is querying for _whether_ there are trucks that match this criterion, not for how many there are.

Comment: type casting on booleans is implicit, AFAIK.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It makes sense, but PHP's pretty good at things like "is number greater than zero" so forcing MySQL to do extra processing, potentially slowing down other queries if this pattern becomes habitual, is messy.

Comment: @tadman: Quite the opposite: by querying for a true/false rather than obtaining the entire recordset then throwing it away, your DB interactions will be _vastly_ faster. Only the `if (x, true, false)` is redundant; this query _should_ return `COUNT(\`id\`) > 1`, and the logic should absolutely _not_ be left to the PHP layer. I admit that in saying this I am arguing against what Ant did in his answer, not what the OP did and, as such, it's not clear to me that we're actually disagreeing. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You are right. Usage of `if` is redundant here. Alternate suggested in the answer.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Just to point out in the context of this question.. count(id) should be > 0. Thanks :-)

Comment: `However you need to loop through the query result to find if it is true or false` Nah not really

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this logic inside the query, you can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM `trucks` WHERE `plate` = '$plate'
```

That's probably the most efficient method. It will return 1 if it finds an entry, which php can see as a boolean true

Comment: It's not very obvious, but I very agree. `TOP 1 1`.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM trucks WHERE plate = :plate");

    $sth->bindParam(':plate',$plate, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sth->execute();

    if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) 
    {

        //true

    } 
    else 
    {

        //false

    }
```

Comment: This is okay, but it's a waste. There is no need to obtain the entire resultset.

Comment: And not all databases support `rowCount()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but as the "entire resultset" is a single id (or none), I don't see an appreciable difference.

Comment: @DigitalChris: No it's not. This answer gets _all_ trucks meeting the criterion.

Comment: I'm assuming $plate refers to the license plate number of the truck which should only result in one id being returned as all license plates numbers are generally unique.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what Ant said. Why else would you want it as a Boolean unless it referred to the availability of one truck?

Comment: @Ant: "Assuming" is the word. Until the OP says this I won't assume that it's true. Especially as he has an ID -- why would you have this if Plate were already unique?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we can just agree to disagree.

Comment: @Ant: I prefer to reach conclusions but okay

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean) casts

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php